# Obtener la fecha del primer y último día de la semana pasada PHP

Tags: php

He investigado y no he podido obtener la fecha del primer y último día de la semana pasada a partir de la fecha actual, he estado usado lo siguiente, pero no me funciona muy bien:

```
$f = date("Y-m-d"); //Fecha Actual
$lastday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$f   -6 day")); //Fecha del último día de la semana pasada
$firstday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$pastweekday   -6 day")); // Fecha del primer día de la semana pasada
```

El resultado debería darme: 2016-07-04(Primer día) y 2016-07-10 último día.

Quisiera saber si existe alguna función, seteando que lunes es el primer día y el domingo el último día de la semana.

Comment: Muchach@s, y si quiero sacar el primer dìa hàbil? es decir, sin festivos, sábados o domingos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La respuesta anterior pero mejorada utilizando una función y un par de validaciones de las fechas límite:

```
public function inicio_fin_semana($fecha){

    $diaInicio="Monday";
    $diaFin="Sunday";

    $strFecha = strtotime($fecha);

    $fechaInicio = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last '.$diaInicio,$strFecha));
    $fechaFin = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('next '.$diaFin,$strFecha));

    if(date("l",$strFecha)==$diaInicio){
        $fechaInicio= date("Y-m-d",$strFecha);
    }
    if(date("l",$strFecha)==$diaFin){
        $fechaFin= date("Y-m-d",$strFecha);
    }
    return Array("fechaInicio"=>$fechaInicio,"fechaFin"=>$fechaFin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando la función srttotime de php podes obtenerlo fácilmente.

```
<?php

$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));

$first = strtotime('last Sunday -7 days');
$last = strtotime('next Saturday -7 days');

echo date('Y-m-d', $first);
echo '<br>';
echo date('Y-m-d', $last);

?>
```

El resultado es:

```
2016-07-03
2016-07-09
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta es excelente Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Habría que definir que significa primer y último día de la semana en tu aplicación, por lo que veo sería el domingo el primer día de la semana y sábado el último.

Según la documentación de php, a partir de la versión 5.6 la semana empieza el lunes para [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.formats.relative.php), entonces voy a asumir que estás usando la versión más reciente, o sea php7.

Teniendo en cuenta esto, necesitamos encontrar el sábado de la semana pasada y el domingo de hace "2 semanas":

```
$firstday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('sunday last week last week'));
$lastday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('saturday last week'));
```

Otra opción un poco más bonita para hallar el domingo del $firstday es:

```
$firstday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('sunday -2 weeks'));
```

Si necesitas algo más orientado a objetos puedes probar con [DateTime.](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php)

Comment: Si el Lunes es el primer día y el Domingo el último día Saludo!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me funcionó gracias no sabía esta forma! Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El lunes de la semana actual y el domingo de la semana actual.

```
echo $lunes_semana_actual = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday -1 weeks'));

echo $domingo_semana_actual = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('sunday -0 weeks'));
```