# Como listar fecha de inicio y fin de una semana especifica

Tags: php, javascript

Lo que se desea es lo siguiente, una función que reciba como parámetro, el numero de semana de un año en concreto  y me devuelva la fecha en que inicia y termina esa semana. por ejemplo

```
function weekStartEnd($weekNumber,$year){
  $firstDateOfWeek=date('w',strtotime('???'));
  $lastDateOfWeek=date('w',strtotime('???'));
  return [$firstDateOfWeek,$lastDateOfWeek];
}
```

El problema es que no se como emplear `strtotime`, o `mktime` para obtener la `fecha de inicio y fin de esa semana`.

En resumen, una función que pueda responder a la pregunta, ¿Cuando inicia y termina la semana 1 del año 2018? 
Y que devuelva como resultado

del 01/01/2018 al 06/01/2018

Si la solución puede ser `javaScript` también es aceptada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por si a alguien le sirve, despues de tanto investigar, tuve que formular busquedas en ingles y me dieron esta solucion.

```
function getStartAndEndDate($week, $year)
    {
        //setting the default time zone
      //  date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

        //getting the
        //$firstWeek = date('W',strtotime("January 1 $year", date(time())));
        //echo "Year : ".$year."<br/>"."Week : ".$week."<br/>";
        $firstWeekThursDay = date('W',strtotime("January $year first thursday",date(time())));

        if($firstWeekThursDay == "01")
        {
            $time      = strtotime("January $year first thursday",date(time()));
            //echo $time."<br/>";
            //echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time)."<br/>";
            $time      = ($time-(4*24*3600))+(((7*$week)-6)*24*3600);
            //echo $time."<br/>";
            //echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time)."<br/>";
            $return[0] = date('Y-m-d', $time);
            $time += 6*24*3600;
            $return[1] = date('Y-m-d', $time);
            //print_r($return);
        }
        else
        {
            $time = strtotime("January 1 $year", time());
            //echo "<br/>".$time."<br/>";
            //echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time)."<br/>";
            $time      = ($time-(4*24*3600))+(((7*$week)-6)*24*3600);
            //echo $time."<br/>";
            //echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time)."<br/>";
            $return[0] = date('Y-m-d', $time);
            $time     += 6*24*3600;
            $return[1] = date('Y-m-d', $time);
            //print_r($return);
            //echo "<br/>End of Hi<br/>";

        }
        return $return;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Si usas programación orientada a objetos te dejo las funciones con Datetime:

```
protected function lastWeekDay($week, $year)
{
    $date = new \DateTime("{$year}-01-01 00:00:00");
    $date->setTimestamp($date->getTimestamp() + $week * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    return $date;
}

protected function firstWeekDay($week, $year)
{
    $lastWeekDay = $this->lastWeekDay($week, $year);
    return $lastWeekDay->setTimestamp($lastWeekDay->getTimestamp() - (86400 * ($lastWeekDay->format('N') - 1)));
}
```

Si quieres usar mktime y strtotime: te dejo las siguientes:

```
protected function lastWeekDay($week, $year)
{
    $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $year) + ($week * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    return date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
}

protected function firstWeekDay($week, $year)
{
    $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $year) + ($week * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    $monday = $timestamp - 86400 * (date('N', $timestamp) - 1);
    return date('Y-m-d', $monday);
}
```

Saludos

Comment: Sería oportuno comentar que si los estás declarando como métodos de instancia, entonces  `ClassName::firstWeekDay` debiera llamar a `$this->lastWeekDay`. También añadiría que en el primer caso, las funciones devuelven un objeto `DateTime` sobre el cual hay que usar el método `format` para obtener un string, mientras que la segunda solución devuelve strings ya formateados.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el siguiente `script` de `PHP`

```
<?php
$year=2014;
$month=1;
$day=26;

# Obtenemos el numero de la semana
$semana=date("W",mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year));

# Obtenemos el día de la semana de la fecha dada
$diaSemana=date("w",mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year));

# el 0 equivale al domingo...
if($diaSemana==0)
    $diaSemana=7;

# A la fecha recibida, le restamos el dia de la semana y obtendremos el lunes
$primerDia=date("d-m-Y",mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day-$diaSemana+1,$year));

# A la fecha recibida, le sumamos el dia de la semana menos siete y obtendremos el domingo
$ultimoDia=date("d-m-Y",mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day+(7-$diaSemana),$year));

echo "<br>Semana: ".$semana." - año: ".$year;
echo "<br>Primer día ".$primerDia;
echo "<br>Ultimo día ".$ultimoDia;
?>
```

También te puede ayudar leer estas dos respuestas de SO

[Obtener la fecha del primer y último día de la semana pasada PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16842/obtener-la-fecha-del-primer-y-%C3%BAltimo-d%C3%ADa-de-la-semana-pasada-php)

[Cómo puedo obtener el primer y ultimo día de una semana concreta en Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7003/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-obtener-el-primer-y-ultimo-d%C3%ADa-de-una-semana-concreta-en-javascript)

Comment: Amigo, probe con esos script, pero no me funciona, ya que me pide el parametro $day y $month, y este no lo tengo, solo tengo $week y $year. abajo encontré una funcion que hace lo que necesito, muchas gracias